# Insert value to IndexedDB in Angular2

Tags: angular, indexeddb

I am using IndexedDB using Angular2.
For that i am following the below **github** 
link.
https://github.com/gilf/angular2-indexeddb

I am creating db like this.

```
     ngOnInit(){
    db.createStore(1, (evt) => {
                    let objectStore = 
   evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
                        'Userdetails', { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });

                    objectStore.createIndex("name", "name", { unique: false });
                    objectStore.createIndex("email", "email", { unique: true });

                });

        }
```

But when i am trying to insert value to **Userdetails** table,that is not working.For inserting i am using below code.

```
db.add('Userdetails', { name: 'name', email: 'email' }).then(() => {
    // Do something after the value was added
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Can anyone please tell me where exactly i am doing wrong.I am very new to this **angular2-indexeddb**.Please help me.

Comment: what do you mean that 'is not working'? Do you have an error message? Nothing happen?

Comment: Yes @Francesco I was getting error like this .
You need to use the createStore function to create a database before you query it!

Now that is solved.I was doing some mistake while writing code.

Comment: have you done this `db = new AngularIndexedDB('myAppDb', 1);` ?

Comment: Can someone answer this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513944/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-indexeddb-in-angular-6

Answer (score 1):

`createStore`, now `openDatabase` is async method. So, below will work.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    let db: AngularIndexedDB = new AngularIndexedDB('myDb', 1);
    db.openDatabase(1, (evt) => {
      let objectStore = evt.currentTarget.result.createObjectStore(
        'people', { keyPath: 'id', autoIncrement: true });

      objectStore.createIndex('name', 'name', { unique: false });
      objectStore.createIndex('email', 'email', { unique: true });

    }).then(function() {

      db.add('people', { name: 'nameq', email: 'email' }).then(() => {
        // Do something after the value was added
      }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });
   });

   db.openDatabase(1).then(function() {
    db.getAll('people').then((person) => {
        console.log(person);
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
   });
  }
```